# Oracle add sequential query rows if missing

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

In Oracle 19c I have a data like:

```
with t as (
select 1 Cat, 1 id, 11 val from dual
 union all
select 1, 3, 33 from dual
 union all
select 2, 2, 22 from dual
 union all
select 2, 4, 44 from dual)
select * 
  from t
```

In query result I want to get `4` rows per every `cat` with ids 1-4 and if there was no such `id` in that `cat` a `val` must be null:

| cat | id | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 3 | 33 |
| 1 | 4 |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 2 | 22 |
| 2 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 4 | 44 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `PARTITION`ed join with a row-generator:

```sql
SELECT t.cat,
       i.id,
       t.val
FROM   (SELECT LEVEL AS id FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4) i
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t
       PARTITION BY (t.cat)
       ON (i.id = t.id)
```

Which outputs:

> | CAT | ID | VAL |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 11 |
> | 1 | 2 | *null* |
> | 1 | 3 | 33 |
> | 1 | 4 | *null* |
> | 2 | 1 | *null* |
> | 2 | 2 | 22 |
> | 2 | 3 | *null* |
> | 2 | 4 | 44 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c9d17d368591be128d4a3efb620fa0b1)*